# After second time the user can login if i use subscribe

Tags: angular

When i use this mock up i dont have problems.

```
  login(userName: string, password: string): void {

if (!userName || !password) {

        this.messageService.addMessage('Please enter your userName and password');
        return;
      }
      if (userName === 'admin') {
        this.currentUser = {
          id: 1,
          userName: userName,
          isAdmin: true
        };
        this.messageService.addMessage('Admin login');
        return;
      }
      this.currentUser = {
        id: 2,
        userName: userName,
        isAdmin: false
      };
      this.messageService.addMessage(`User: ${this.currentUser.userName} logged in`);

}
```

and the user logs in from first time,but i implemented web api now and is returning data.when i am using the same code in subscribe method then the first time i cant login,even the user name and password are correct after second login try i can log in.Why is that where is my mistake?

```
 constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  login(userName: string, password: string): void {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.allUsers = users;
      let findUserInfo = this.allUsers.filter(user => user.userName == userName && user.password == password);
      alert(findUserInfo);
      console.log("******")
      console.log(findUserInfo);
      console.log("******")

      if (!userName || !password) {

        this.messageService.addMessage('Please enter your userName and password');
        return;
      }
      if (userName === 'admin') {
        this.currentUser = {
          id: 1,
          userName: userName,
          isAdmin: true
        };
        this.messageService.addMessage('Admin login');
        return;
      }
      this.currentUser = {
        id: 2,
        userName: userName,
        isAdmin: false
      };
      this.messageService.addMessage(`User: ${this.currentUser.userName} logged in`);
    });
```

Comment: Are you returning a list of user names and plain text passwords from your API?

Comment: I am returning json objects,byt for testing porposes yes the password is string

Comment: Could you share your `UserService`-code and the code where you call the `login` method?